# How to send ID from handler page to aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on asp.net and stuck in this problem. I have applied full text search functionality using handler. And now I want that when user chooses a name from list (which is suggested after entering keywords) page should be redirected to that person's profile

```
    <link href="Content/jquery.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
$("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>").autocomplete('Search_CS.ashx');
     });
   </script> 

 <div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
  </div>
```

When a user types a name in textbox, it returns usernames with matching search text. It is handling in handler(ashx file)

```
 public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
string prefixText = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strcon))
{

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select Profile_ID,FirstName, LastName from UserProfile where FirstName like '%' + @SearchText + '%' OR LastName like '%' + @SearchText + '%'";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                sb.Append(sdr["FirstName"]).Append(" ").Append(sdr["LastName"]).Append(Environment.NewLine);

            }
        }
        conn.Close();
        context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());

    }
}
   }
```

Now when user types "Tom" a list is opened with all the users having name "tom". When user selects "Tom John", page should navigate to Tom John profile. And this can be done by selecting Profile_ID of the username which is selected by the user. How to redirect user to particular user's profile page through Profile_ID.

Comment: Why are you using jQuery twice? that too `jquery-1.3.2` and `jquery-1.4.1`

Answer (score 0):

you can achive that using on select event here is example

```
$(function() {

          $("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>").autocomplete({
               source: "Search_CS.ashx",
               // you need to handle on select event 
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                // here you can redirect ur user page 
                // http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote
                window.top.location = this.value;
              }
         });
                      });
```

Comment: but how will I return Profile_ID of the selected user from handler?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: "Search_CS.ashx",
        select: function(event, ui) {
            window.location.href = 'profile.aspx?user=' + ui.item.value;
        }
    });
});
```

See [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) for more details.

The "source" attribute stands for the name of the datasource, a server-side script which should return JSON data. Once user enters a string (minLength: 3) the plugin queries "Search_CS.ashx?term=user_input", and expects a JSON output as below

```
[
   {"id":"123","label":"John","value":"123"},
   {"id":"435","label":"Bill","value":"435"}
]
```

So, in terms of your code it should look as

```
string prefixText = context.Request.QueryString["term"];

....

sb.Append("[");
while (sdr.Read())
{
    string u = sdr["FirstName"].ToString() + " " + sdr["LastName"].ToString();

    if (sb.Length > 1)
       sb.Append(",");
    sb.AppendFormat("{{\"id\":\"{0}\",\"label\":\"{0}\",\"value\":\"{0}\"}}", u); 
}
sb.Append("]");
```

Comment: but how will I return Profile_ID of the selected user from handler?

Comment: by doing this.. List is not being populated

Comment: You need to debug your code. Open developer tools in the browser (F12) and see if console has any js-errors when typing a value in the textbox. Try to call Search_CS.ashx?term=user_input directly from the browser and see its output. It should return the json output as per example.